# MVC4, TinyMCE.MVC, can't set tinymce control content after Ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce

MVC4, downloaded TinyMCE.MVC : content of tinymce control need to be retrieved by Ajax call and set into that tinymce control. So far my attempts to set html content in tinymce control have failed. I have to use Ajax call. Is there way to do that?
Thank you.

VIEW:

```
<div id="divTinyMCE">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.myContent)
</div>
<button type="button" id="btnGetContent" onclick="getContent()">Get Content</button>

@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getContent() {

        var parm1 = 1;
        var parm2 = 2;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Home/GetContent',
            data: { parm1: parm1, parm2: parm2},
            success: function (data) {                    
                alert("data from ajax = " + data.toString()); // data is html

                //tinymce.set(data.toString());  // does not set anything
                //tinymce.html(data);            // does not set anything
                $("#tinymce").html(data);        // does not set anything
            }
        });  // AJAX call

    }

</script>
}
```

CONTROLLER :

```
public ContentResult GetContent(int parm1, int parm2)
{
    string contentFound = findContent(parm1); // contentFound is HTML string
    return Content(contentFound);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out:
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data);